# Firebase Storage: "Invalid argument in put at index 0: Expected Blob or File

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I keep getting an `Invalid argument in put at index 0: Expected Blob or File` error. The funny thing is the argument is totally a file...

Here is the code:

```
var file = document.getElementById('cke_69_fileInput')
          .contentWindow.document.getElementById('cke_69_fileInput_input').files[0];

var storageUrl = 'noticias/imagenes/';
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(storageUrl + file.name);
console.warn(file); // Watch Screenshot
var uploadTask = storageRef.put(file);
```

Here's the screenshot of the actual file warn just before the error asking for a file...
[image]

Comment: What version of firebase.js are you using?

Comment: @MikeMcDonald 3.2.1

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try converting file to blob...

```
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
    var blob = new Blob([evt.target.result], { type: "image/jpeg" });

    var storageUrl = 'noticias/imagenes/';
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(storageUrl + file.name);
    console.warn(file); // Watch Screenshot
    var uploadTask = storageRef.put(blob);

  }

  reader.onerror = function (e) {
      console.log("Failed file read: " + e.toString());
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

Comment: Put {type:mime} for uploading files of all formats.

Comment: @Aaron Saunders - thanks! And while blob works I'm wondering what firebase expects as a "file" in this case?

Comment: one can also use {type:file.type} to specify mime type